# different data window for FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE

Tags: sql, oracle

Following query gives strange results. It looks like the default window for FIRST_VALUE is always UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING and for LAST_VALUE is like CURRENT_ROW AND CURRENT_ROW. Why is that?

```
select 
to_char(INVOICEDATE,'iw') WEEK,
SUM(total) AS TOTAL_SUM,

FIRST_VALUE(to_char(INVOICEDATE,'iw')) OVER (order by SUM(total)) minimum,
FIRST_VALUE(to_char(INVOICEDATE,'iw')) OVER (order by SUM(total) DESC) maximum,
LAST_VALUE(to_char(INVOICEDATE,'iw')) OVER (order by SUM(total)) max_2,
LAST_VALUE(to_char(INVOICEDATE,'iw')) OVER (order by SUM(total) ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) max_3

from invoice

WHERE to_char(INVOICEDATE,'iw') < 9
group by to_char(INVOICEDATE,'iw')
order by to_char(INVOICEDATE,'iw')
```

**Here are the result:**

[image: HERE ARE THE RESULST]

Comment: `BETWEEN CURRENT_ROW AND CURRENT_ROW` would be **just the current row**, I don't think that's the case.

Comment: Yes, but 'max_2' behaves in this way..

Comment: Check [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions004.htm#i97640): *If you omit the windowing_clause entirely, then the default is RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW.*

Comment: Please don't provide result as image, put it as text. Also without having your source data it is difficult to help you.

Comment: But if so, why the two FIRST_VALUE are showing the same results for all rows? and LAST_VALUE is different for each one, sorry but i dont get it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, i get it now.
Both functions have window like UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW but the FIRST_VALUE gets the first row so no matter how many will follow it always shows the first result, and the LAST_VALUE shows always the CURRENT_ROW.
Thank You all!

Comment: But in your example FIRST_VALUE columns show different output: `08` and `02`. And this is an expected outcome if you use `ASC` sorting for the first one and `DESC` for the second. Perhaps you should edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to follow what's happening if you look at one calculated column at a time, and order the output to match the `over` clause ordering.

For the first-value minimum only, ordered by total:

```
select 
  to_char(invoicedate,'iw') week,
  sum(total) as total_sum,
  first_value(to_char(invoicedate,'iw')) over (order by sum(total)) minimum
from invoice
where to_char(invoicedate,'iw') < 9
group by to_char(invoicedate,'iw')
order by total_sum;

WEEK  TOTAL_SUM MINIMUM
---- ---------- -------
08         30.7 08     
04        34.65 08     
01        35.65 08     
03        38.66 08     
05        41.58 08     
06        56.43 08     
07        59.48 08     
02        63.45 08
```

The ordering you are using (in `over()`) means that the first row processed by `first_value` is 08 so it sees itself. The second row in that ordering is week 04, but it considers rows `unbounded preceding to current row`, so it looks at 08 and 04, and takes 08 as that is still (and always, by that ordering) first. And so on.

For the first-value maximum only, ordered by total descending:

```
select 
  to_char(invoicedate,'iw') week,
  sum(total) as total_sum,
  first_value(to_char(invoicedate,'iw')) over (order by sum(total) desc) maximum
from invoice
where to_char(invoicedate,'iw') < 9
group by to_char(invoicedate,'iw')
order by total_sum desc;

WEEK  TOTAL_SUM MAXIMUM
---- ---------- -------
02        63.45 02     
07        59.48 02     
06        56.43 02     
05        41.58 02     
03        38.66 02     
01        35.65 02     
04        34.65 02     
08         30.7 02
```

This the reverse of the previous one; the first row seen using that order is for week 02; the second row considers 02 and 07 and uses 02 as that is still (and always, by that ordering) first.

For the last-value maximum only, ordered by total:

```
select 
  to_char(invoicedate,'iw') week,
  sum(total) as total_sum,
  last_value(to_char(invoicedate,'iw')) over (order by sum(total)) max_2
from invoice
where to_char(invoicedate,'iw') < 9
group by to_char(invoicedate,'iw')
order by total_sum;

WEEK  TOTAL_SUM MAX_2  
---- ---------- -------
08         30.7 08     
04        34.65 04     
01        35.65 01     
03        38.66 03     
05        41.58 05     
06        56.43 06     
07        59.48 07     
02        63.45 02
```

Now the rows are considered in a different order to the previous block. The first row with that ordering is back to 08, and we're still using the default window clause, so only that one can be used.

The second row is week 04, and only 08 and 04 can be considered; and *by that ordering* 04 is now the last value seen. That's is the same for all the subsequent rows; the last value seen is that row, because of the ordering.

The window is the same, but the ordering you're using affects which rows are actually in that window. For your `max_3` calculation you are changing the window to include all rows; you could also reverse the default window so it (kind of, effectively) matches the one used for `first_rows`:

```
  last_value(to_char(invoicedate,'iw')) over (order by sum(total)
    rows between current row and unbounded following) max_3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this great and complete answer!